# Typescript Javascript one line If…else…else if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this piece of code:

```
 if (service.isHostel) {
            return new Hostel({url: service.url});
        } else {
            return new booking({url: service.url});
        }
```

that I want to express in 1 line,

```
service.isHostel ? Hostel({url: service.url}) : return new booking({url: service.url})
```

but I have a compilation error:

Expression expected.

Comment: Try `return service.isHostel ? new Hostel({url: service.url}) : new booking({url: service.url})`

Comment: are you missing the `new` key word near the hostel object ?

Comment: the whole code should be return ```return service.isHostel ? new Hostel({ url: service.url }) : new booking({ url: service.url });```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only write expressions(piece of code which returns are value) inside ternary operation. `return` is a statement which can't be used inside the expression of ternary operators.

Here you have to `return` both the values you can use `return` before ternary

```
return service.isHostel ? new Hostel({url: service.url}) : new booking({url: service.url})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `new` operator as well for `Hostel` and omit the return return statement inside of the ternary.

```
return service.isHostel ? new Hostel({url: service.url}) : new booking({url: service.url});
```

Another version is to choose different classes.

```
return new (service.isHostel ? Hostel : booking)({url: service.url});
```

Comment: I like this method because if you move `(service.isHostel ? Hostel : booking)` to  a seperate function, you arrive at the factory pattern